# Beaglebone without DAC (from Digital to Analog Converter)?

Tags: beagleboneblack

In the beaglebone there are many analog input, but are there any analog output?
It means, is there any DAC inside the beaglebone?

Are there alternatives?

Comment: check manual: https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/BBB_SRM.pdf . manual will be your best friend. i checked the index, there is no dac chapter

Comment: There is no DAC Available for BBB Units directly. You may have to use external DAC Circuits or modules to implement DAC. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i'm new in beaglebone, but see if there is something that worth for you....
[tutorial here](https://www.element14.com/community/community/designcenter/single-board-computers/next-gen_beaglebone/blog/2013/07/06/bbb--building-a-dac)
s

- EDIT:

  Well, your question was too large in options to answer, to start, for a DAC CS4334, you can do the connection as follow:
- MCLK (Master Clock) = pin P9_25
- SDATA (Serial Audio Data Input) = P9_28
- LRCK (Left/Right Clock) = P9_29
- SCLK External Serial Clock Input = P9_30

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: right, just trying to help....i'm new, so i'm not able to comment in your question....